# Making a hash table the size of a user input

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashtable

So from what I understand a hash table is pretty much an array of linked lists, so I am trying to make an array to be the size of a specific user input so if the user inputs '5' there will be 5 buckets (or indexes) in the hash table. The problem is that when I try to create the array in my .h file it says that the array length must be a constant. Should I define this somewhere else other than in the .h or is it possible to do it some other way? Thanks!

Here is my .h file:

```
#include <string>


using namespace std;

struct athlete{

    string discipline;
    string gender;
    string team;
    string event;
    string venue;
    string medal;
    string name;
    string country;
    athlete* next;

};


class hTable{

private:
    int tableSize; // need this to be user input
    athlete* HashTable[tableSize]; // hashTable is an array of athletes


public:
    hTable();
    int Hash(string key);
```

- also i apologize for grammar English is not my first language

Answer (score 4):

If you want a dynamically sized array it needs to be dynamically allocated.

```
HashTable = new athlete[tableSize];
```

And in the header file `HashTable` would be defined as:

```
athlete* HashTable;
```

It's probably better to use a `std::unique_ptr` as it makes memory clean up easier.

Usually `std::vector` is a preferred data structure than a plain array.

And for the record, a hash table is not just an array of linked lists.

Comment: Probably just better to recommend the OP use a `vector` instead

Comment: @NirFriedman True, but at some point he'll need to know about dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: Sure, I'm just not sure if that day is today. Have an upvote!

Comment: @NirFriedman Thanks! I did update the post to mention using a vector instead.